# Adding UseCookieConsent to Umbraco causes HTTP 417: Expectation Failed in the back office

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, cookies, umbraco, umbraco-10

I added a cookie consent banner to my website using the standard .NET UseCookieConsent() middleware. However, this started throwing 417 error codes in the back office, resulting in the nodes failing to load and the backoffice becoming completely unusable - the same happens when deployed to my remote host. Error message shown below:

GET https://localhost:44318/umbraco/backoffice/umbracoapi/backofficeassets/GetSupportedLocales 417 (Expectation Failed)

Possibly unhandled rejection: {"errorMsg":"Failed to get cultures","data":{"Type":null,"Title":null,"Status":417,"Detail":null,"Instance":null,"Extensions":{"traceId":"00-d9b0ecde07e5815e972858eade6a6394-afc12ffd089185a8-00"}},"status":417,"xhrStatus":"complete"}

Additional errors with the same error code are raised for the following API calls:

- GetCheck
- AllowsCultureVariation
- GetSections
- GetTours

This may relate to the [ValidateAngularAntiForgeryTokenAttribute](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v10/main/src/Umbraco.Web.BackOffice/Filters/ValidateAngularAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.cs) , which returns an error from the call to `ValidateRequestAsync on [BackOfficeAntiforgery](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v10/main/src/Umbraco.Web.BackOffice/Security/BackOfficeAntiforgery.cs), which then throws the Expectation Failed result, however I don't know how to resolve this issue from my side without there being changes to the Umbraco source code.

Any ideas?

Comment: I faced something similar with cookie-script, I had to register all the cookies used by the umbraco backend to the cookie manager platform (cookie-script to my case).